# About super and mult-inherit of python class

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

I use Python 3.6.3

I have following code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print("init parent")

class PP:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print("init PP")


class Child(PP, Parent):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print("init child")
        super().__init__()

exp=Child()
```

I expect:

```
init child
init PP
init parent
```

but I got:

```
init child
init PP
```

when I try to print the MRO，I got the correct answer.

```
print(exp.__class__.mro())

[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.PP'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Why  is there no print of `parent`?

Comment: `PP.__init__` needs to call `super()` too. Required reading: [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't automatically call `__init__` of `Parent`. You have to do it explicitly with `super().__init__()` in `PP`:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print("init parent")

class PP:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print("init PP")
        super().__init__()


class Child(PP, Parent):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print("init child")
        super().__init__()

exp = Child()
```

Now the output is:

```
init child
init PP
init parent
```